# django concurrency request two url, each request header is wrong to each url

Tags: django

concurrency to request django app with two url, each url request header I give one id, like urla id=1, urlb id=2, but when i get from django view from request header, I get urla's id from request header is 2 ...so confused...post body is ok

client code

```
#coding=utf-8
import threadpool

import requests

HOST = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
urls = ['/health', '/x2']
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'HOST': 'xx.com'}

pool = threadpool.ThreadPool(5)

def request_api(n):
    url = urls[n%2]
    print('---------------------start request url {}'.format(url))
    headers.update(url=url)
    body = dict(
        url=url
    )
    r = requests.post(url=HOST + url, headers=headers, json=body)
    print(r.status_code)

reqs = threadpool.makeRequests(request_api, range(5))
[pool.putRequest(req) for req in reqs]
pool.wait()
print('over')
```

server code

```
# coding=utf-8
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http.response import HttpResponse


class ApiHealthCheck(APIView):
    def post(self, request, request_id='', **kwargs):
        print('api_health_check: {},{},{}'.format(request.path, request.META.get('HTTP_URL'), request.data))
        return HttpResponse("ok")


class ApiHealthCheck2(APIView):
    def post(self, request, request_id='', **kwargs):
        print('api_health_check2: {},{},{}'.format(request.path, request.META.get('HTTP_URL'), request.data))
        return HttpResponse("ok")
```

server print

```
api_health_check: /health,/health,{u'url': u'/health'}
api_health_check2: /x2,/health,{u'url': u'/x2'}
api_health_check: /health,/health,{u'url': u'/health'}
api_health_check2: /x2,/x2,{u'url': u'/x2'}
api_health_check: /health,/health,{u'url': u'/health'}
```

attention one of them have wrong,path not match META's content,body is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, I found the problem, not django problem, it is my fault.

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'HOST': 'xx.com'}
```

headers is a global variable, concurrent request can concurrent modify this header, so request django, django get wrong header